Strategy to add login upon JWT expiration to existing codebase APIs (without making changes in hundreds of places)
There is an existing codebase with just under 100 API calls scattered throughout. The JWT expires every X minutes, and we want to trigger a user log-in prompt upon expiry (currently, if the token expires, it just ends up in an endless window.location.reload loop).
Right now, our API calls are in our UI code in the form of fetch(), and sending the JWT as a header. The JWT is generated in our Project.cs, and it is stored in our sessionStorage.
As far as my research showed, JWTs don't come with an inherent onExpiry() type function which triggers as they expire. This is exactly the type of behaviour I would like to mimic. I am currently considering several options - I'd like some advice on which to pick, as well as if there are any I am not considering.

Modify every single existing fetch() call (nearly 100 of them) in the codebase to go through an authentication first, before catching the 401 Authentication Failed error and prompting login. This is not ideal due to the sheer amount of calls being made, and meaning we would have to individually test every API.

Add a wrapper function which intercepts every attempted fetch() call, and validate the token there before passing it to the controller. I feel like this is bad practice, because we would have to modify the keyword fetch in order to hit this wrapper function. This means we either change each API call from fetch() to wrapperFunctionForFetch(), but it seems like bad practice and it will be unintuitive to create APIs later on for those who are unfamiliar with the codebase? Please let me know if this assumption is incorrect.

Implement a simple polling function that uses tokenExpiryTime as the timeout, and validate the token at this time. However, I'm not extremely knowledgeable with JavaScript and JWTs, and I'm not sure if over time there will be a discrepancy created between the tokenExpiryTime and the setTimeout() that we are using. Is there a different way to implement this sort of polling logic that is cleaner?


Appreciate any advice and answers, thank you!

You may be able to use the window error event to catch any instances of a 401 error and redirect then. That one event could be registered in a standalone script which gets imported into all pages it is required. Not 100% if this would work (never tested) but it might be a relatively non intrusive way to cache and deal with the authentication issue.

@DanielBlack that actually sounds like a great idea. I'll look into that.

If it works for you, feel free to add your own answer with how you got it working. I would be interested to see the full setup :)

@DanielBlack unfortunately, it seems like it is not possible because window error events are for handling JavaScript errors and not HTTP ones :/ thank you for the suggestion though! Learned a lot
